# It seems evident + to/for

Tags: prepositions

I am unsure about the following: if I want to say that something is clear for me in particular, should I say:
It is evident **to** me that...
It is evident **for** me that...

Comment: _Evident_ takes _**to**_ for a perceiver. And you don't need _seem_; _evident_ covers the same territory.

Comment: "Evident" on its own conveys certainty. Adding "seem" weakens it, in saying that you might be mistaken. You might not need seem, but it does have its uses.